# p:dataTable not showing updated records from database on Dialog close

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog

I need your help in refreshing the `dataTable` component on closing the `Dialog`. I tried many ways to refresh the `dataTable`, but it is not retrieving the updated record, unless I have refreshed the full page by clicking on the "Go" button which is next to the URL in the address bar.

The xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="Requests">
<h:panelGroup id="table">
<p:fieldset id="Pendings" legend="Pending Requests">
<div id="refresh">
<p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" value="#{hrd.pendingRequests}" paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom" filteredValue="#{hrd.filteredPendingRequests}">

<p:column headerText="Req. Date" sortBy="#{hr.requestDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{hr.requestDate}" >
<h:outputText value="#{hr.requestDate}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">View</f:facet>
<p:commandButton id="submitbutton" update=":Requests:#{hr.dialogueName} "
oncomplete="PF('#{hr.certificateDialogue}').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hr}" target="#{hrd.selectedRequest}"/>
</p:commandButton>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</div>
</p:fieldset>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:dialog id="CertificateDialog" header="Cert1" widgetVar="CertificateDialog" >
<p:ajax event="close" update=":Requests" listener="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}"/>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

I tried to update the dataTable only, but it is not refreshing. Although, I have tried to update the full form using @form and @all and again the dataTable was not refreshed.

The updateDataTable method:

```
public void UpdateDatatable(CloseEvent event) {

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":Requests");

}
```

Comment: Create an mcve. And define 'not refreshed'…  what if there is,an ajax response that contains a datatable, it, for jsf, is refreshed. Maybe **you** forgot to update the content of the list in the backingbean.

Comment: Can you please explain more in defining 'not refreshed'? Also, I have modified the update component in the backing bean to update the dataTable but it is not refreshing

Comment: **you** should define what technically does and does not happen when something is 'not refreshed' like I explained above. Check ajax network stuff, check bean side if it is updated there. I can't do that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to update a component from `ManagedBean` using `RequestContext.update()` you should not use the relative component id, because you'd have nothing to relate to.

To fix your problem remove `:` before `Requests` in your listener.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("Requests");
```

If you feel updating a component from managed bean, increases cohesion. You can use a `p:remoteCommand` can call if from your javascript any time you want.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" update=":Results" />
```

And you can call the above `remoteCommand` from javascript or in your case from dialog as below:

```
<p:dialog onhide="updateTable()">
...
</pdialog>
```

My suggestion is to move `p:dialog` out of the `h:form` in which you placed the `dataTable`. Because In future if you get into situation where if need to update the `h:form` from `p:dialog` while its still open, updating the very own `h:form` in which the `p:dialog` is placed, would cause the dialog the `p:dialog` to close abruptly.

If you your `p:dialog` out for `h:form` then you might not need the `UpdateDatatable()` listener itself. `update` from your `p:ajax` would do the job for you.